# Merge into a table by joining 2 others

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to use a merge statement to update one table by joining two other tables. The update statement I have written is painfully slow so I would like to replace it with a merge. This is the script giving me problems.

```
UPDATE T1 
SET TitleID = T2.TitleID 
FROM Customer T1 
INNER JOIN Customer_Temp T3 
    on T1.importFK = T3.importFK 
INNER JOIN Customer_Title T2 
    on T2.TitleDescription = T3.TitleDescription 
    and T2.ID = @ID
```

Comment: what's the exact problem you are facing ? an error message ? unexpected results ?

Comment: The problem is it's too slow.

Answer (score 2):

`MERGE` probably is not going to increase performance.  For this query:

```
UPDATE T1 
    SET TitleID = T2.TitleID 
    FROM Customer T1 INNER JOIN
         Customer_Temp T3 
         ON T1.importFK = T3.importFK INNER JOIN
         Customer_Title T2 
         ON T2.TitleDescription = T3.TitleDescription AND T2.ID = @ID;
```

You want indexes.  I would recommend:

- `Customer_Title(ID, TitleDescription, TitleId)`
- `Customer_Temp(TitleDescription, importFK)`
- `Customer(importFK)`